# Javascript const keyword used differently

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, graphql

during an online course I found this syntax:

```
const graphql = require('graphql');
const{
     GraphQLObjectType
} = graphql;
...
```

My question is: What is that means the second part of the code? Is like import some property name from the graphql library?
I checked on const definition, some other forums but I dind't find anything.

Thanks

Comment: [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). Equivalent to `const = graphql.GraphQLObjectType;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an example of '[destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)', which allows you to easily extract parts of an object or array into a variable.

```
const { GraphQLObjectType } = graphql;

// is the same as

const GraphQLObjectType = graphql.GraphQLObjectType;
```

```
let obj = { a: 0, b: 1 };
let { a, b } = obj;

// is the same as

let obj = { a: 0, b: 1 };
let a = obj.a;
let b = obj.b;
```

```
var arr = [0, 1, 2];
var [ a, b ] = arr;

// is the same as

var arr = [0, 1, 2];
var a = arr[0];
arv b = arr[1];
```